# codeigniter home page not working without hard refresh

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi i have a problem with codeigniter home page all other pages working fine but home page is showing 500 error while append website.com/index is shows the home page.

This is the code of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You say it works when you do a hard refresh? You've cleared your cache yeah?

Comment: try to change from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: Look into Apache's error.log, you should see at least some hint for the 500 server error.